# Tags interfering with next_post_link();

Tags: theme-development, loop, next-post-link

I am creating a theme in WordPress.

I am using `query_posts('tag=front')` to limit the posts on the front page. However, I want to let the user navigate through all posts, **regardless of tags** when on the a permalink page. I am using `next_post_link()`; to deal with this.

I am using this to limit the posts on the `index.php`:

`query_posts( 'tag=front' );`

I am using this to let the user click through each project, on `single.php`:

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post &rarr;', TRUE); ?>
```

However, it is **only looping through posts tagged with `front`,** and not all posts regardless of tags. I want it to loop through **all**.

You can see it live here: http://kurt-theme.info/

Comment: What do you mean by 'a permalink page'?

Comment: oh dear lord, `query_posts` *faints*

Comment: What would you recommend as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

1. `query_posts()` should not be used, look into `pre_get_posts` hook.
2. Whatever you do inside `index.php` template does not influence inside of `single.php` template. Two different top level templates aren't (normally) loaded at the same time.
3. You are explicitly requesting `next_post_link()` to limit next post to the same category via third argument, are you sure that's not your issue?

Comment: You were right. It was the third argument. Thanks!